# Laravel5.1 jsValidation Unique rule issue

Tags: validation, unique, laravel-5.1, validationrules, formvalidation-plugin

I'm using laravel-jsValidation, https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation, everything is working fine except Unique rule !
Here what I have :
Rules :

```
protected $userValidate=[
          'lastname' => 'required|max:100|min:2',
          'firstname' => 'max:100|min:2',
          'username' => 'required|unique:users|min:2',
          'email' => 'required|unique:users|email|max:255',
          'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',  ];
```

Get Users List Function :

```
public function getUsers(){
  $validator = JsValidator::make($this->userValidate);      
  return view('admin.usersList')->withValidator($validator);}
```

Store Function :

```
public function store(Request $request){   
  $data = $request->all();

  $v = Validator::make($data, $this->userValidate);           

  if ($v->fails())
  {
      return redirect()->back()->withErrors($v->errors());          
  }  

  $user = User::create([
        'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
        'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],                        
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']), 
        'confirmed' => 1,                 
    ]);       

  return redirect('admin/usersList');}
```

The problem is when I enter username or email, an error message appears under its input in form:

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

NB : I set : `'disable_remote_validation' => false,`
and when I change it to `true`, it works fine only if I enter username and email which don't exist in users table !

What's the mistake in my code ?

[image]

Comment: It's already true, 
In fact I'm using a modal form to create new user, and I'm trying to validate my form by jsValidation.

Comment: here what happens :
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2lliwwx&s=9#.Vnr3jE92GC4

Comment: Huh. Apparently that is the whole error message. You should probably add that picture to your question by using the `edit` button on the bottom left.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know that there's ability to add image ^^

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the problem is : this package does not support remote validation, as I can read in Config/jsValidation.php :

> /*
>        * Enable or disable Ajax validations of Database and custom rules.
>        * By default Unique, ActiveURL, Exists and custom validations are validated via AJAX
>        */
>       'disable_remote_validation' => false,

So how can I validate this rule via AJAX ? please is there any tutorial ?

Comment: This issue is resolved in master branch. Try if your issue is resolved and I will release a new version

Answer (score 1):

I'm the maintainer of [laravel-jsvalidation](https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation) package. This issue is fixed in **release 1.3.0**

The rules **Unique**, **ActiveURL**, **Exists**, and custom validations are validated automatically. Just enable it

```
 'disable_remote_validation' => false,
```

Comment: Please mention where to add these code lines clearly. Unless this is not helpful at all.

Answer (score 0):

Unique validation need column name after table name. I assume your column name is `email` in database. Your rule for email should look like this:

```
'email' => 'required|unique:users,email|email|max:255',
```

Comment: @BKF I am little confuse now. You wrote rules not to create username & email which is already in database. That's why you are seeing this error. I don't see any problem. Actually what are you trying to do?

Comment: Unique rule means you can't create new user row contains that field (here : username and email), what I want to do : when I create new user with an email already token then an error message appears saying : this username / email is already token. that's all :)

Comment: @BKF Yes, it should be. Because, as your code you can't create new row with an existing username and email. You can create row with new username and email which are not in database yet.

Comment: Is there any js-form-validator for laravel 5.1 works fine may be I'll use it instead of this one :)

Answer (score 0):

```
return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:`admin_users`,email',
            'phone' => 'required|unique:admin_users,phone',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|max:16'
        ];
```

Comment: Hi, here are some guidelines for your answer: It is **not recommended** to post code-only answers, consider to also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.